# What's the difference between build and emulate after creating a projet

Tags: cordova, build

Good day,

I am very new with Cordova and I could install cordova, create a project.
cordova requirements command successes

I read [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/cli/index.html) some other step

We should run build

```
cordova build
```

or

```
cordova build android
```

But what does build?
Do we have to build before running

```
cordova emulate android
```

Or can I run emulate without building the project?
Or do we have to build only before sending the project to GooglePlay?

I also would like to install the notification plugin, do I have to rebuilt after a modification as adding a plugin, modifying the project?

Many thank for your clarification about build

Answer (score 0):

```
cordova build
```

will build your app for any platform you added.

```
cordova build android
```

will only build the APK file for the Android platform.

```
cordova emulate android
```

will build your APK *and* try to launch it on either an emulator or connected Android device. So yes, you can emulate without running build first, as this is part of the emulate command.

After adding a plugin you will need to rebuild, just like after any change to your code.